# Scheme: creating a random range

Tags: random, integer, scheme, range

In scheme I have to use random to define a procedure that accepts no arguments and returns an integer in the range 1 to 10, inclusive and i cant use if. im lost =(

Comment: Does your Scheme provide a `random` function?

Comment: yes my scheme provides a random function

Comment: (+ 1 (random 10)) If you can't work this out by yourself, you should change your courses. Programming is not for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Scheme provides a `random` function, you want either

```
(define (1-10-rand)
    (+ 1 (random 10)))
```

or

```
(define (1-10-rand)
    (floor (* 10 (random))))
```

depending on whether you have `(random n) --> integer in [0, n-1])` or `(random) -> float in [0,1]`

Be advised that this isn't standards-compliant. For *absolute* portability, write your own RNG.

Comment: i tried it and i got a syntax error. if i have to define procedure throw-die and it randomly returns an intger 1 to 6, what is lambda? and could i use (+ 1 (random 10)) for the body?

Comment: To `throw-die` you `(define (throw-die) (+ 1 (random 6)))`

Comment: Actually, what does calling `(random)` at the REPL do? `(random 5)`?