# Scheme - generate random

Tags: scheme

How do I generate random in Scheme?  Is there a special form or would I have to create a procedure?  And if so, how do I do that?  (I'm trying to create a procedure called random-choice that inputs two strategies and returns one at random.)

Comment: This bad boy might help even though it is closed.

[Scheme: creating a random range [closed]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334891/scheme-creating-a-random-range

Comment: [SRFI 27: Sources of Random Bits](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-27/srfi-27.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure is called, surprisingly enough, `random` - although the exact syntax might be different depending on the Scheme interpreter in use (read the documentation!), but the general idea is as follows:

```
(random)
=> 0.9113789707345018
```

For returning one of two possible values, this will do the trick in Racket:

```
(define (random-choice a b)
  (if (zero? (random 2)) a b))
```

Notice that the `2` argument passed to `random` forces it to randomly return one of two possible values: `0` or `1`. So if `(random 2)` evaluates to `0` then `a` is returned, otherwise `b` is returned.

```
(random-choice 4 2)
=> 4
(random-choice 4 2)
=> 2
```

Comment: Not in standard Scheme it isn't. Most implementations have a facility for creating random numbers, but they don't all use the same name or the same signature. For example in Guile there is a `random` procedure, but it requires at least one argument and always returns an integer. So your code will cause an error in Guile (and many other Scheme implementations as well, I imagine). It's okay to give implementation-specific answers, if there are no standard answers, but you should at least mention that it is implementation specific and to which implementation it is specific.

Comment: @sepp2k If by "standard" you include "final" SRFIs (and I do), [SRFI 27](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-27/srfi-27.html) specifies an interface for getting random numbers.

Answer (score 10):

Standard Scheme does not provide a random number generator, and although most Scheme implementations provide one, they tend to differ in their details. If you want to write a portable Scheme program, it's easy to build your own random number generator; here's a method due to Knuth:

```
(define random
  (let ((a 69069) (c 1) (m (expt 2 32)) (seed 19380110))
    (lambda new-seed
      (if (pair? new-seed)
          (set! seed (car new-seed))
          (set! seed (modulo (+ (* seed a) c) m)))
      (/ seed m))))
```

Calling `(random)` returns a random fraction between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). The random fractions cycle with period *m*. Calling `(random seed)` resets the seed of the random number generator, so that two random sequences starting from the same seed will be identical; dates in the form YYYYMMDD make good seeds (that's Knuth's birthday above). If you want to flip a coin, say: `(if (< (random) 1/2) 'heads 'tails)`.

Sometimes you want a random integer over a range. The `randint` function shown below returns a random integer on the range *lo* (inclusive) to *hi* (exclusive); *lo* defaults to 0:

```
(define (randint . args)
  (cond ((= (length args) 1)
          (floor (* (random) (car args))))
        ((= (length args) 2)
          (+ (car args) (floor (* (random) (- (cadr args) (car args))))))
        (else (error 'randint "usage: (randint [lo] hi)"))))
```

Random numbers such as these are good enough for simple simulations, but beware they are not suitable for cryptographic applications. If you are interested, I have several random number generators, including some suitable for cryptographic applications, at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Random%20Number%20Generators).

Answer (score 1):

Since your other question was about implementing a spaceship game in DrRacket, I will assume, that by Scheme you mean one of the teaching languages in DrRacket.

The way to find information on available functions in DrRacket is simple. Write, say, `random` in the interaction window. Place the cursor on top, and then press F1.

The documentation on the `random` in htdp-languages is here:

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html?q=random#(def.*htdp-beginner.*((lib._lang/htdp-beginner..rkt)._random))](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html?q=random#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang/htdp-beginner..rkt%29._random%29%29)

One way to return a random value:

```
(list-ref (list "one" "two") (random 2))
```

Here (random 2) will return 0 or 1.
The list-ref will thus return either the entry
with index 0 or index 1 of the list.

The advantage of using the above approach
is that it is easy to extend to more values
than two.