# Cryptographically secure random number generation in Scheme

Tags: random, scheme

The emergence of the cryptocurrency Bitcoin has made implementations of cryptographically secure PRNG's (pseudo random number generators) indispensable. Following up on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674165/scheme-generate-random) and the [blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Random%20Number%20Generators) referred to within it, I was wondering if things had changed in the last 4 years and whether there was a known implementation in scheme, something giving access to well-established algorithms as well as entropy generation from the kernel.

Comment: Crypto-PRNGs were already indispensable before Bitcoin. But sadly Scheme is one of those languages where implementing stuff like this is not really nice. So i doubt there is something ready for use and i also would recommend switching the programming language for this task. If you want to stick to Functional Programming, then use one with a good C-interface (like Haskell). Performance will be a problem, but grabbing entropy from the system sounds even worse in regards to Scheme.

Comment: @sascha Thank you very much. I am already using java/python/haskell and simply wanted to replicate my implementations in scheme just for fun. Never mind, i ll use whatever `slib` provides.

Comment: @sascha As far as grabbing entropy to initialize a large enough seed is concerned, can't I just read bytes from `/dev/urandom` ?

Comment: I was actually thinking the kind of system calls would be more complex, but sure, /dev/urandom is a nicely file-like accessible way. Seems like you now only have to care about performance and the mostly bitlogic-based algorithm-descriptions of CPRNGs.

Comment: @sascha v grateful for your help.